# How to compare two datetime form Json data with the current datetime in PHP 8

Tags: php, json, datetime, php-8.1

I want to compare two DateTime from JSON data with the current DateTime. compare the start date & end date with the current date to data between these two dates. If dates do not match give 0 answer.

---

````
$json = '[ 
  {
     "type":"playlist",
     "id": "35",
      "start_datetime": "2022-09-28 09:48",
      "end_datetime": "2022-09-28 09:51"
  },
  {
     "type":"asset",
     "id": "4",
      "start_datetime": "2022-09-29 07:00",
      "end_datetime": "2022-09-29 07:30"
  },
  {
     "type":"asset",
     "id": "4",
      "start_datetime": "2022-09-29 09:00",
      "end_datetime": "2022-09-29 09:30"
  }
]';

function find_events($events, $date) {
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    foreach ($events as $event) {
      $from = (new DateTime($event['start_datetime']));
      $to = (new DateTime($event['end_datetime']));
      if ($date >= $from || $date <= $to) {
           $r= "{$event['start_datetime']} to {$event['end_datetime']}".'<br>';
        }else{
          $r=0;
        }
    }
      return $r;
}

$events = json_decode($json, true);
print_r(find_events($events, '2022-09-29 07:00'));

?>```
````

Comment: ...ok. and what specific problem are you having when you run your code? What's your actual question about this?

Comment: this gives me always 0 answers. even dates are equal... I

Comment: I want that if the dates match show data ...if not give me 0 answer

Comment: `this gives me always 0 answers`...no, it doesn't. Demo: https://3v4l.org/3gsK3

Comment: What PHP default time zone do you have set on your system? And btw., you realize that this would _overwrite_ `$r` each time, in case there should ever be _multiple_ matching events, yes?

Comment: also, give wrong answer

Comment: `if the dates match`... be more specific, please. You want to check if the date provided falls within the "from" and "to"  dates, is that correct? Also, do you want it to analyse _all_ the dates in the array? Because right now it will just return the result from the last item in the array - since you are overwriting the result with every loop.

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: Well firstly, please answer the questions in my last comment, to clarify the exact requirements for us.

Comment: _"also, give wrong answer"_ - that's because, logic wrong. If you want events where the given date falls between their start and end time - then your two comparisons need to be joined by a logical AND, `&&`, not OR.

Comment: I also try in array but I giving me all data

Comment: I also try && but its not working

Comment: That's because of the already mentioned issue, that you are _overwriting_ `$r` in each loop iteration. Your second event is a match - but the third one isn't, and so you are explicitly setting `$r = 0` in the last loop iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the wording is not very clear, I am assuming you want to check if the date provided falls within the "from" and "to" dates. I also assume you want it to analyse *all* the dates in the array.

Right now it will just return the result from the last item in the array - since you are overwriting the result with every loop. And also, your comparison logic is wrong:

```
if ($date >= $from || $date <= $to)
```

says *"if the date is after the 'from' date OR before the 'to' date"*. But to check if it's between those dates, clearly *both* conditions will need to be true.

To fix this, change the `||` to `&&` in that line above, and also you can concatenate the results into a string, instead of overwriting them, so that you see every result.

```
function find_events($events, $date) {
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    $r = "";
    
    foreach ($events as $event) {
      $from = (new DateTime($event['start_datetime']));
      $to = (new DateTime($event['end_datetime']));
    
      if ($date >= $from && $date <= $to) {
           $r.= "{$event['start_datetime']} to {$event['end_datetime']}".'<br>';
      }
      else{
          $r.= "0<br>";
      }
    }
     
    return $r;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/30eIo